# TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'str' object in SCRAPY in python

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, typeerror

I have written the following spider using scrapy in python like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
from twisted.internet import reactor
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class GivenSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        select = Selector(response.body)
        title = select.xpath("//a[@class=listinglink]/@href").extract()
        print title
#       for t in title:
#           title4 = MyItem()
#           title4['content'] = t
#           yield title4

#       filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
#       with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
#           f.write(response.body)

configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
runner = CrawlerRunner()

d = runner.crawl(GivenSpider)
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()
```

I am running it:

```
$ python runTimeSpider.py
```

The following output I give is:

```
INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
INFO: Spider opened
INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/> (referer: None)
ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "runTimeSpider.py", line 17, in parse
    select = Selector(str(response.body))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/selector/unified.py", line 80, in __init__
    _root = LxmlDocument(response, self._parser)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/selector/lxmldocument.py", line 24, in __new__
    cache = cls.cache.setdefault(response, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 433, in setdefault
    return self.data.setdefault(ref(key, self._remove),default)
TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'str' object
ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "runTimeSpider.py", line 17, in parse
    select = Selector(str(response.body))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/selector/unified.py", line 80, in __init__
    _root = LxmlDocument(response, self._parser)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/selector/lxmldocument.py", line 24, in __new__
    cache = cls.cache.setdefault(response, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 433, in setdefault
    return self.data.setdefault(ref(key, self._remove),default)
TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'str' object
INFO: Closing spider (finished)
INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 514,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 16284,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 21, 8, 28, 26, 17960),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/ERROR': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'spider_exceptions/TypeError': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 21, 8, 28, 24, 986319)}
INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

How can I print titles? Ut has an error:

```
TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'str' object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is that you want to convert `response.body` to a selector. `response.body` is a string -- and on strings you cannot do XPath queries.

So either use

```
select = Selector(response)
```

or call XPath queries right on the `response` object because it is an object which has `xpath` as a method included:

```
title = response.xpath("//a[@class=listinglink]/@href").extract()
```